# oAuth2 authorization server's login screen not coming in latest spring boot version

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

We are trying to build a custom auth server with oAuth2 using spring boot and to be accessed by multiple clients using OAuth2Sso. The same code is working with spring boot version 1.5.6.RELEASE but it is not working with 2.3.1.RELEASE. The login screen is not coming up on auth handshake.

The ResourceServerConfig code is as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

And the AuthorizationServerConfig is as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("ClientId")
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("user_info")
                .autoApprove(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

When client is trying to access any secure page, it is redirecting to oAuth server but not loading the login in screen.The error is coming as below istead.

```
<oauth>
<error_description>Full authentication is required to access this resource</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

If we add @Order(1) at the ResourceServerConfig class, then the login screen is coming but after successful authentication, it is not coming redirecting back. Instead it is showing an error
[image: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/authorize?client_id=ClientId&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9193/login&response_type=code&state=QIAz6j]

but the same workflow is working for the older spring boot version mentioned above without any change. Please enlighten me there is any change is the framework with Spring Security 5 and what is the remedy to get the behavior in the latest version.

Comment: The error message says it: you have to configure a redirect URL.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security 5 does not support Authorization Server as of yet (version 5.3.3.RELEASE)
https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/14/spring-security-oauth-2-0-roadmap-update

However spring security has announced a community driven project
https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/15/announcing-the-spring-authorization-server

As for now, with spring security 5 in your resource server you can either use an external authorization server or, configure one of your own standalone spring authorization server with spring security oauth 2.3+
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix